# PHPUnit 7.5.6 + Coverage 6.0.7 = No code coverage driver is available

Tags: php, phpunit, sublimetext3, macos-mojave, test-coverage

I'm wracking my brain here.

### Problem

When I try to run my tests with code coverage output, I receive the following output:

`Error: No code coverage driver is available`

What data in the below is incorrect or not displayed that can help make this work? (Note: I've had it working in the past - years ago on a different version of everything but Sublime Text.)

---

### Details

```
macOS             10.14.4, 
Sublime Text      3.2.1 (build 3207), 
PHP               7.2.14, 
Zend              3.2.0, 
Xdebug            2.7.1
PHPUnit           7.5.6
PHP Code Coverage 6.0.7
```

Here is what `php -v` outputs:

[image]

I have been trying a lot of different variations, answers, and tutorials and seem to be missing a key piece somewhere. So, I have also tried this with and without `MAMP Pro 5.3` running. In either case, Terminal is always:

[image]

---

When using MAMP, the `php.ini` file settings look like this:

```
[xdebug]
MAMP_Xdebug_MAMPzend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
;xdebug.profiler_enable=0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/Applications/MAMP/tmp"
```

---

When I install an Xdebug plug-in for Sublime Text 3 - I can enter a debugging session that does function.

Comment: Which version of Phpunit are you using?  And have you tried executing the phpunit CLI-test-runner with that exact PHP binary you are referring to in your screenshots? For the php.ini the zend_extension line looks fishy, looks to me it does not work albeit your screenshot says differently. Perhaps there is some MAMP specific configuraiton method you need to address, can't say I'm not a MAMP user.

Comment: Sorry juts getting back. Honestly, since posting this, I haven't tried again. I did all the search-fu I could regarding MAMP PRO it's version of PHP compared to that of macOS and so on. Still at a loss. With that said, I'm not much of a "metal" person; so, I can't answer the first two questions as I'm not sure what they mean.

Comment: Ok, these questions I asked toward trouble-shooting the issue. The message "Error:         No code coverage driver is available" means that the configuration requested code-coverage but the xdebug extension is not loaded. For troubleshooting this configuration needs to be checked *when running* Phpunit.

You can run Phpunit in the shell: `$ php [<php options>...] -f <path-to-phpunit> -- [<phpunit options>...]`, this way it's easier to control. HTH.

Comment: Thanks! Yep. Running PHPUnit in shell, I'm good with, I think. I have PHPU configured to output coverage to a folder in the XML config. When it actually goes to do the export - compilation to HTML - that's when I get the error. If I remove the coverage output setting in the config, I can still run the tests. (OS recently had to be reset; so, I'm starting from base zero re xdebug.)

Comment: That makes sense. Only if you require the output of code coverage (cc), then Phpunit will complain (show the error).